# Rust Iterator [E0053] and [E0308] using `From` implementation

Tags: rust, iterator

I seem to be having issues, with Rust, and would certainly appreciate some help.

I've a custom `struct` that implements the Iterator trait, and a separate `struct` (also an Iterator) that I'd like to be able to *wrap* anything that presents itself as an iterable. Some of this seems achievable via generics, however, when getting specific within the wrapper `struct` things seem to go sideways.

**My main goal is to accept any iterable that returns `Option<char>`, and preform some parsing/collection of characters.**

Here's a toy example that demonstrates the core features I'm trying to implement...

**`src/main.rs`**

```rust
#!/usr/bin/env rust


struct IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    iter: I,
}

impl<I, T> Iterator for IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

impl<I, T> IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>
{
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self { iter }
    }
}

impl<I, T> From<I> for IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    fn from(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self { iter }
    }
}


// ============================================================================


struct CustomIterator {
    data: Option<(usize, String)>
}

impl CustomIterator {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn new<S>(string: S) -> Self
    where
        S: Into<String>
    {
        let string: String = string.into();
        let data = Some((0, string));
        Self { data }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CustomIterator {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some((index, string)) = self.data.take() {
            let mut iter = string.get(index..).unwrap().char_indices();
            if let Some((_, c)) = iter.next() {
                self.data = iter.next().map(|(i, _)| (index + i, string));
                return Some(c);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}


// ============================================================================


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn map() {
        let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
        let m = v.into_iter().map(|n| n * 2);
        let mut i = IteratorHolder::new(m);
        assert_eq!(i.next(), Some(2));
    }

    #[test]
    fn chars() {
        let s = String::from("abc");
        let c = s.chars();
        let mut i = IteratorHolder::new(c);
        assert_eq!(i.next(), Some('a'));
    }

    #[test]
    fn custom_iterator() {
        let c = CustomIterator::new("zxc");
        let mut i = IteratorHolder::new(c);
        assert_eq!(i.next(), Some('z'));
    }

    #[test]
    fn from_iter() {
        let c = CustomIterator::new("zxc");
        let mut i = IteratorHolder::from(c);
        assert_eq!(i.next(), Some('z'));
    }
}
```

**Above all seems to function without errors**

---

What I'm finding strange is when getting specific with `From` implementations there be various type errors appearing.

For example where I to implement `FromStr` on `IteratorHolder` a `E0053` error is generated...

> method `from_str` has an incompatible type for trait expected fn pointer
> `fn(&str) -> std::result::Result<IteratorHolder<I, T>, _>` found
> fn pointer `fn(&str) -> std::result::Result<IteratorHolder<CustomIterator, char>, _>`
> [E0053]

**`src/main.rs` (snip)**

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::num::ParseIntError;


impl<I, T> FromStr for IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    type Err = ParseIntError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<IteratorHolder<CustomIterator, char>, Self::Err> {
        let iter = CustomIterator::new(s);
        let hold = IteratorHolder { iter };
        Ok(hold)
    }
}
```

... And being more generic generates `E0308` errors...

> mismatched types expected type parameter `I` found struct `CustomIterator`
> [E0308]

```rust
impl<I, T> FromStr for IteratorHolder<I, T>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    type Err = ParseIntError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let iter = CustomIterator::new(s);
        let hold = Self { iter };
        Ok(hold)
    }
}
```

---

Essentially I'm *face-planting* on how to make `IteratorHolder` more *self sufficient*, with regards to *`From`* implementations. My main goal is to have a parser, similar to `IteratorHolder`, that can read characters from iterators regardless of where those characters are sourced from; eg. file, stream, string. etc.

Comment: When you say `impl<I, T> FromStr for IteratorHolder<I, T> where I: Iterator<Item = T>` you're saying "for every `IteratorHolder` I will implement `FromStr`." Yet, your implementation returns only an `IteratorHolder` for `CustomIterator`, which is clearly not what your type declaration said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aplet123 mentioned, you are claiming to implement `FromStr` for an `IteratorHolder` containing *any* iterator, however you really just want to implement it for `IteratorHolder<CustomIterator>`. Here's a working version, cleaned up a bit and more idiomatic (particularly: I removed `T` since it is redundant, it already exists as `I::Item`):

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a7213be0b2f949653038e806c17a3f98)

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;
use std::str::FromStr;

struct IteratorHolder<I> {
    iter: I,
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for IteratorHolder<I> {
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> IteratorHolder<I> {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self { iter }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> From<I> for IteratorHolder<I> {
    fn from(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self::new(iter)
    }
}

// ============================================================================

struct CustomIterator {
    data: Option<(usize, String)>,
}

impl CustomIterator {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    fn new<S: Into<String>>(string: S) -> Self {
        Self {
            data: Some((0, string.into())),
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CustomIterator {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some((index, string)) = self.data.take() {
            let mut iter = string.get(index..).unwrap().char_indices();
            if let Some((_, c)) = iter.next() {
                self.data = iter.next().map(|(i, _)| (index + i, string));
                return Some(c);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

impl FromStr for IteratorHolder<CustomIterator> {
    type Err = ParseIntError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(IteratorHolder {
            iter: CustomIterator::new(s),
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That totally worked!... Here I've been making a proverbial forehead shaped stain against a wall of compiler errors for days. I'll certainly have to spend some more time with the corrected code to fully grasp where I went wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help! To be clear, the `T` parameter wasn't the cause of any errors, it was just redundant. The issue was that writing `impl<I: Iterator> FromStr for IteratorHolder<I>` is like claiming that you would can convert a string into a holder containing whatever kind of iterator that the consumer of the impl desires. Instead of saying "I can turn a string into `IteratorHolder<CustomIterator>`", you were saying "I can turn a string into `IteratorHolder<AnyIteratorYouWant>`", which isn't even possible. How can you turn a string into any possible iterator, e.g. a network download iterator?

Comment: The reason why that is correct for things like `From<I>` is that you would be correct to say "I can turn any type `I` into `IteratorHolder<I>`". On the other hand, you can't say "I can convert a string into `IteratorHolder<I>` for any type `I`".